# Ruby Begin/Rescue Syntax inside of a String

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, syntax, rescue

I have an interesting problem I am trying to solve.

Ultimately, I want to execute a block of code that looks something like this:

```
array.each do |element|
  begin
    eval(element)
  rescue => e
    puts "Unable to process #{element}"
  end
end
```

However, because of some other code that I cannot control/edit, the stuff I want to execute is being put into an array as a string, and executed line by line from there.

For instance, if I want to run something like:

```
puts 'test'
```

It goes into the array like this:

```
execution_array << "puts 'test';"
```

A more complex example:

```
array.each do |element|
  puts element
end
```

Ends up looking like this:

```
execution_array << "array.each { |element| puts element };"
```

Ultimately, I want my begin/rescue/end stuff to be a line that gets executed, but I can't get the syntax to work correctly, and things aren't being rescued properly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: can you show a tangible example of what you mean by "things aren't being rescued properly? Are you sure you're adding newlines to the string you're evaling?

Comment: Hold the phone. `eval`? What's going on here? Why are you using `eval` instead of pushing in Proc functions?

Comment: @max-pleaner, I wasn't even sure with where to start since I couldn't find much info on doing begin/rescue/end in a single line, so I tried this which is definitely wrong:
execution_array << "array.each do { |element| begin eval(element) rescue puts 'Error' end}

Comment: @tadman I am not familiar with Proc functions, but in any case, my issue doesn't appear to be with eval, it's the begin rescue, I will look into Proc functions though to see if they are better for this case

Comment: you need to put semicolons in there, like `begin; eval(element); rescue; puts "error"; end` ` i agree with what tadman is saying about avoiding eval but you did say it was something you can't control

Comment: With a lambda you can do this: `array << -> { array.each { ... } }` where that's just regular Ruby code inside the block, not text. Then you can "evaluate" the block with `block.call` or, if you need to, by rebinding that to evaluate in different contexts. Passing around Ruby blocks is almost always better than slinging raw code about.

Comment: Awesome, I will look more into lambda if I can make that work with the code I can't edit.

I got the semicolon stuff to work in a quick example, so I think I can extrapolate from there. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Tennessej if you have your code in multiline format, you can pass a heredoc to eval which will avoid the need to enter semicolons.